# How to get device information only from location

Tags: 16.04, development

Is there a way to get the information of a device in the terminal, providing only his location?

For example
I whant to get /dev/sca product information, such as fabricant and model.

Usually i just go to /dev/by-id/ but i am working with some old ubuntu versions.

**Solution**

inxi --disk-full; hdparm -I /dev/sdb; smartctl -i /dev/sdb; udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sdb

Comment: If it is Ubuntu 16.04 or older it is of topic on this site.

Comment: Try running `sudo lshw`. It will list some hardware information.

Comment: David it not only for 16.04 for 18.04 and 20.04.

Comment: So, with _location_ you mean just its path on /dev? Your command is unnecessary complex. Why don't just grep one of these? `inxi --disk-full; hdparm -I /dev/sdb; smartctl -i /dev/sdb; udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sdb`

Answer (score 0):

This command solve my problem.

```
     sudo sed -n -e 1p -e 6p <<< $(tac <<< $(lshw| pcregrep -M '.*((\n|.)*/dev/sdb1)') | pcregrep -M '(/dev/sdb1(\n|.)*?vendor)'|tac)
```

This scrip uses pcregrep to find in "lshw"´s output the line with "/dev/sda1" and keeps all the lines previous to the match, then invert the lines order with tac, filters again with pcregrep from "/dev/sda1" to the first match of "vendor", then with tac it orders it agains like was before and finaly sed extract line 1 and 6 with sed.

The output is this.

```
         vendor: ADATA  
         serial: AA00000000000489
```

Had to install pcregrep to use regular expressions in multilines.